# Proof of Lyapunov instability theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lyapunov-functions

I'm reading through my university notes and I've noticed we only proved the Lyapunov stability and asymptotical stability theorems, and haven't touched upon instability. I'm familiar with the concept of the Lyapunov function, I just find it a bit strange that even on the internet I haven't been able to find a detailed proof, or even the formal statement of the instability theorem. I'm wondering if anyone knows where can I find a detailed proof of the Lyapunov instability theorem on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: You can take a look at Lawrence Perko's book

Comment: For stability you need that *all* close solutions will stay close; for instability it is enough to have just *one* solution that eventually leaves the neighborhood. The nature of the proof of Lyapunov theorems is such that it works for all the solutions, and hence the instability theorem is easy to formulate but it will be of very limited scope. A more useful generalization is given by Chetaev, so you better study [Chetaev's theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Chetaev_theorems).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!